# How to convert UTF-8 numbers into characters

Tags: text, encoding, utf-8

I have got a very big text file (~150 MB) encoded in UTF-8. The content of the text contains both UTF-8 readable characters and entity numbers.

When displayed by a text editor (TextWrangler, NotePad++...), the text content is as below:

```
zygoma  <B><FONT SIZE='+1'>zygoma</FONT></B>/z&#652;&#618;/ (g&#601;&#650;m&#601;)</FONT>
```

When this text file is read by a web browser, the content is correctly displayed as:

- zygoma **zygoma**/zʌɪ/ (gəʊmə)

I want all the UTF-8 numbers (like `g&#601;&#650;m&#601;`)to be converted to readable characters (like **gəʊmə**) so that, when opened by a text editor, the text file will be like this:

```
zygoma  <B><FONT SIZE='+1'>zygoma</FONT></B>/zʌɪ/ (gəʊmə)</FONT>
```

I have tried using encoding tools provided by TextWrangler and Notepad++... but there is no luck. (there are some online tools to do this task but my text file is too big for them).

I wonder if there is a tool or a way to convert those UTF-8 numbers into their equivalent readable characters.

Can you please help? Thank you.

Comment: Those are HTML entities. Just HTML-decode the file using any tool/language you want.

Comment: Well @tripleee, if you can't provide help, just restrain your patronisation. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/ tool (Russian lang).

Translated version: http://bit.ly/15O0eQW (eng)

**updated:**

Try this script https://gist.github.com/Funfun/6839052

Comment: Thanks, but as said, my text file is 150 MB, too big for such online tools.

Answer (score 2):

[EditPad Pro](http://www.editpadpro.com) can do this:

[image: screenshot pre-conversion]

Using the `Convert` - `&#65535; and &#xFFFF; -> Character` command (and assuming that the current file is set to UTF-8 and that you're using a font that contains the required glyphs), you get

[image: screenshot post-conversion]

When you save that, you get a correctly UTF-8-encoded file with or without BOM, as you choose.

---

<sub>Disclaimer: I am the translator for EPP's German version (but I'm doing this for free, because this editor is excellent).</sub>

Comment: Many thanks to you. This is why I love StackOverFlow. EditPad does the trick.